# Imagemagick killing colour quality when resizing image

Tags: jpeg, imagemagick

I'm trying to resize a bunch (450+) of images through imagemagick, they all start at 500x500 and I've written a script to resize them to about 5 different sizes.

Now I've converted them I notice that the colour quality takes a noticeable hit. Is there anything I can change in my command to increase quality a little?

Command: `convert input.jpg[0] -background black -density 72 -resize 440x440 -quality 100 -strip output.jpg`

I can't upload the actual file but here is a cropped version (with padding)

Original:
[image]

ImageMagick:
[image]

Comment: try using xnview instead

Comment: Can you please provide an original jpg file? I cannot reproduce the color change with the png file in your question.

Comment: Which operating system? You could try [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/), an improved fork of ImageMagick.

Comment: @mpy I've updated the question with actual jpgs, sorry about the white space!

Comment: @harrymc We use debian so I'll give it a look

Comment: @harrymc Same sort of results unfortunately, thanks anyway! - That being said, upon googling it seems faster so we'll probably switch over to this full time soon

Comment: You use the `-strip` option, which removes the color profile which is present in the original jpeg. If I omit this strip, the resulting file has the same vivid colors -- given the image viewer uses the color profile. What is the purpose of `-strip` here? And, is your question more like: _How to display the image w/o color profile as close to the original as possible?_ (However, I couldn't answer that one...)

Comment: @mpy I've been using that tag for a while believing it did one thing, now realising it does something else. Post this as an answer and that bounty is yours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the `-strip` option, which [tells convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip) to

> strip the image of any profiles or comments.

This includes the *color profile*. Hence, in image viewers that do use the embedded color profile `output.jpg` will look differently as `input.jpg` when using

```
convert input.jpg -background black -density 72 -resize 440x440 -quality 100 -strip output.jpg
```

So, omitting the `-strip` option is the easiest way to get the same colors in `output.jpg`:

```
convert input.jpg -background black -density 72 -resize 440x440 -quality 100 output.jpg
```

---

Another possibility is the following -- if you want to get rid of any comments, but preserve the colors:

1. Extract the color profile.
2. Strip all metadata with `jpegtran` from the debian package `libjpeg-progs` (lossless operation).
3. Resize the image and incorporate the color profile again.

   ```
   convert input.jpg colorprofile.icc
   jpegtran -copy none input.jpg > input_stripped.jpg
   convert input_stripped.jpg -profile colorprofile.icc -background black -density 72 -resize 440x440 -quality 100 output.jpg
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I'll award the bounty as soon as the option becomes available!

Comment: @JamieTaylor : Thanks, but take your time... perhaps someone has a better option for you, nobody of us thinking about at the moment.